# Mongoose to combine data from 2 schemas

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm creating 2 different schemas as below in my mongoose code.

```
    //News Schema
    var newsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      link: { type: String, index: {unique: true, dropDups: true}, required: 'Kindly enter the link of the news' },
      description: { type: String, required: 'Kindly enter the description of the news' }
    });

    //Comment Schema
    var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      text: { type: String, required: 'Kindly enter the comment text'},
      newsId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "News", required: 'Provide the news ID to which this comment belongs' }
    }, 
    {
      timestamps: true
    });
```

It has News and Comment schema. Every News item will have multiple comments and so I'm providing News ID as part of the Comment schema.
When I fetch list of News items, I also want top 3 (or less, if less comments are available) comments to be fetched for each News item. 
Is it possible with either populate or aggregate or combination of them? Or is there any better way to handle it?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with `aggregate`

Comment: @ŞivāSankĂr Can you please provide some reference document or sample to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

**Comments List with Top Three Based on Created Date & Time**

Use aggregation [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to group your document based on the `newsId` and then [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) to control number of items in an array.

```
db.comment.aggregate([
    { '$sort': { 'createdAt': 1 } }, //Where timestamps is true
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$newsId',
            'docs': { '$push': '$$ROOT' },
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'top_three': {
                '$slice': ['$docs', 3]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**News List, With 3 Comments for Each News**

Use aggregation with [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)

```
db.news.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "comments",
        let: { news: "$_id" },
        pipeline: [
            { $match: { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$newsId", "$$news"] } } },
            { '$sort': { 'createdAt': 1 } },
            { $limit: 3 }
        ],
        as: "comments"
    },
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems you didn't understand my question. I am looking for list of "News" that will have max of 3 comments in each News item.

Comment: Answer Updated !